# Convert a recursive sequence formula to explicit

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I need to convert the following formula

$$
a_{n+1} = 5a_n - 6a_{n - 1}
$$

into an explicit formula, so I can just put whatever $n$ and get the $n$-th element of the sequence.

I know how to extract the formula if I have 2 equations, for example:

$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} + b_{n-1}\\
b_n = a_{n - 1} + 2b_{n-1}
$$

A matrix is needed ->
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\\
X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\
b_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And then just calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix and create a diagonal matrix($\Lambda$) and the eigenvector matrix ($P$) with them and get to the equation:
$$
AX = P\Lambda^{n-1} P^{-1}X
$$
And simply multiply everything to get the result in explicit form.

Is there a similar way to calculate explicit form of the equation above?

EDIT: $a_0 = a_1 = 1$

Comment: There are several ways to do what you want, but the most similar to your method is writing $b_n=a_{n+1}$, this will give you a system of two first order recurrence equations, one of them being $a_n=b_{n-1}$.

Comment: For the first one, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to write down the matrix 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
5 &-6\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
so that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n+1}\\
a_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
A
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n}\\
a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then proceed with the eigenvalues/eigenvectors analysis as you are used to.

Comment: ok, so I got to the point where I get this vector:
$\begin{bmatrix}3\cdot3^{n-1}+ 6\cdot2^{n-1}\\3^{n-1}+ 3\cdot2^{n-1} \end{bmatrix} $
but I am not sure whether it is correct

Answer (score 2):

Use generating functions. Rewrite the recurrence relation as
$$
a_{n + 2} = 5 a_{n + 1} - 6 a_n.
$$
Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, multiply the relation by $z^n$, and sum over $n \ge 0$ with the initial values to get
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2} = 5 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} - 6 A(z).
$$
Solve for $A(z)$ and express the result as partial fractions, so we can
$$
A(z) = \frac{a_1 - 2 a_0}{1 - 3 z} - \frac{a_1 - 3 a_0}{1 - 2 z}.
$$
We can interpret these as just geometric series in closed form, so rewriting this gives us
$$
a_n = (a_1 - 2 a_0) \cdot 3^n - (a_1 - 3 a_0) \cdot 2^n.
$$
The same technique (with minor modifications) works for a wide variety of recurrence relations.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve most difference equations is the following. Consider $a_{n+2} = 5 a_{n+1} - 6 a_{n}$ having solutions of the form $a_{n} = r^{n}$. From this it is seen that $r$ satisfies the quadratic equation $r^{2} - 5 r + 6 = 0$ for which the solutions are $r = 2, 3$. Hence $a_{n} = A \ 2^{n} + B \ 3^{n}$, where $A$ and $B$ are to be determined from the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

There are easier ways to do this, but if $x^2=5x-6$ then $(x-2)(x-3)=0$

Now set $b_n=a_n-2a_{n-1}; c_n=a_n-3a_{n-1}$

Then $b_{n+1}=3b_n [+0c_n]$ and $c_{n+1}=[0b_n + ]2c_n$ are in the form you wanted, and your matrix is already diagonal.

Once you have solved this note that $a_{n-1}=b_n-c_n$

Easiest is to note that the roots - here $2$ and $3$ - of the auxiliary equation are the eigenvalues of the matrix, and the answer will therefore be of the form $A\cdot 2^n+B\cdot 3^n$ with $A, B$ determined by some other conditions on the system.

Comment: wow, this sure is a shortcut! But how do I determine A and B?
As I followed @Andreas Caranti's answer I got to $\begin{bmatrix}3\cdot3^{n-1}+ 6\cdot2^{n-1}\\3^{n-1}+ 3\cdot2^{n-1} \end{bmatrix} $, but I don't think this is the answer. Any hint how do I proceed?

Comment: @Mark - $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary - but if you were to know $a_0=p, a_1=q$ you'd solve $A+B=p; 2A+3B=q$ and skip the matrices- or you could plug $b_1=q-2p, c_1=q-3p$ into your matrix method.

Comment: I forgot the initial values, they are $a_0 = a_1 = 1$, sorry but I did not quite get what I need to do with $b_1=q−2p,c_1=q−3p$

Comment: @Mark You should then get $B=-1, A=2$. I assumed that you had a way of plugging initial values into your matrix method - here $b_1=-1, c_1=-2$

Comment: and one more thing, how do we know that $b_n=a_n-2a_{n-1}; c_n=a_n-3a_{n-1}$ should actually be defined like this?

Comment: @Mark You convert the recurrence $a_{n+1}=5a_n-6a_{n-1}$ into the auxiliary equation with the same coefficients $x^2=5x-6$ which factorises as $(x-2)(x-3)=0$ and you take $2, 3$ from there.

Comment: ok, and how do we determine $b_{n+1}$ and $c_{n+1}$. I am sorry for asking too much, but I really need to understand this method

Answer (score 1):

Recursive sequence definition:
$$a_{n+1}=\left\{\begin{matrix}a_0=1&n=0\\a_1=1&n=1\\5a_n-6a_{n-1}&n>1\\\end{matrix}\right.$$

Representation using matrix notation:
$$v_{n+1}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{n+1}\\a_{n}\end{bmatrix}, v_{n}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{n}\\a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}, A=\left[\begin{matrix}5&-6\\1&0\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$v_{n+1}=Av_{n}$$

Derive expression for $v_n$ in terms of initial condition vector $v_1$:
$$v_2=Av_1=A^{2-1}v_1$$
$$v_3=Av_2=A(Av_1)=A^2v_1=A^{3-1}v_1$$
$$v_4=Av_3=A(Av_2)=A(A(Av_1))=A^3v_1=A^{4-1}v_1$$
$$\vdots$$
$$v_n=\cdots=A^{n-1}v_1$$

Now one knows that the multiplication of an eigenvector $x$ of $A$ by $A$ will yield the same result as multiplying $x$ by the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. Therefore, if one can represent the initial condition vector $v_1$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of $A$ then one can replace the matrix multiplication by $A$ with multiplication by the corresponding $\lambda$’s of $A$.
For example supposing $A$ has two unique eigenvalues/vectors represented by $x_1, x_2, \lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively then one could derive the explicit expression for $v_n$ as follows:

Represent $v_1$ as a linear combination of $x$’s:
$$v_1=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$$

Substitute into the formula for $v_n$:
$$v_n=A^{n-1}v_1$$
$$v_n=A^{n-1}\left(c_1x_1+c_2x_2\right)$$
$$v_n=c_1A^{n-1}x_1+c_2A^{n-1}x_2$$
$$v_n=c_1\lambda_1^{n-1}x_1+c_2\lambda_2^{n-1}x_2$$

With all this laid out now one needs to find the eigenvalues/vectors of your specific recursive sequence:
$$Ax=\lambda x$$
$$(A-\lambda I)x=0$$

For non-zero $x$, $A-\lambda I$ must be non-invertible and therefore $\det{\left(A-\lambda I\right)}=0$:
$$\left|\begin{matrix}5-\lambda&-6\\1&-\lambda\\\end{matrix}\right|=0$$
$$\left(5-\lambda\right)\left(-\lambda\right)-\left(-6\right)\left(1\right)=0$$
$$\lambda^2-5\lambda+6=0$$
$$\left(\lambda-3\right)\left(\lambda-2\right)=0$$
$$\lambda_{1,2}=3,2$$

Now to find the corresponding eigenvalues one must solve the equation $\left(A-\lambda I\right)x=0$ for each $\lambda_{1,2}$.

Solving for $x_1$:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}5-3&-6&0\\1&-3&0\\\end{matrix}\right]\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}1&-3&0\\0&0&0\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$x_1 = \left[\begin{matrix}x_{11}\\x_{12}\end{matrix}\right]=t\left[\begin{matrix}3\\1\end{matrix}\right] \hspace{1cm} (t=1) \hspace{1cm} x_1=\left[\begin{matrix}3\\1\end{matrix}\right]$$

Solving for $x_2$:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}5-2&-6&0\\1&-2&0\\\end{matrix}\right]\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}1&-2&0\\0&0&0\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$x_2 = \left[\begin{matrix}x_{21}\\x_{22}\end{matrix}\right]=t\left[\begin{matrix}2\\1\end{matrix}\right] \hspace{1cm} (t=1) \hspace{1cm} x_2=\left[\begin{matrix}2\\1\end{matrix}\right]$$

Find $v_1$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors $x_1$, $x_2$:
$$c_1\left[\begin{matrix}3\\1\end{matrix}\right]+c_2\left[\begin{matrix}2\\1\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$\left[\begin{matrix}3&2&1\\1&1&1\\\end{matrix}\right]\rightarrow\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&2\\\end{matrix}\right]\ \ \therefore c_1=-1,\ c_2=2$$
$$\therefore v_1 = -x_1 + 2x_2$$

Substitute the linear combination representation of $v_1$ into the expression for $v_n$ and use eigenvalues to remove $A$:
$$v_n=A^{n-1}v_1$$
$$v_n=A^{n-1}\left(-x_1+2x_2\right)$$
$$v_n=-A^{n-1}x_1+2A^{n-1}x_2$$
$$v_n=-\lambda_1^{n-1}x_1+2\lambda_2^{n-1}x_2$$
$$\left[\begin{matrix}a_n\\a_{n-1}\end{matrix}\right]=-\left(3^{n-1}\right) \left[\begin{matrix}3\\1\end{matrix}\right]+2\left(2^{n-1}\right)\left[\begin{matrix}2\\1\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now just take the first row of the above answer and simplify for the $a_n$ expression:
$$a_n=-3^n+2^{n+1}$$

And that’s your answer!

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party but I just wanted to give a detailed answer in case anyone else had a similar question XD.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: find a constant $c$ such that $a_{n+1} + ca_n$ is a geometric progression