# Convert $a_{n+1} = 5 a_n \, ( 1 - a_{n} )$ to explicit formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I need to convert the following formula

[formula](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?a_%7Bn+1%7D%20%3D%205%20%5Ccdot%20a_n%20%5Ccdot%20%28%201%20-%20a_%7Bn%7D%20%29)

$$a_{n+1} = 5 a_n \, ( 1 - a_{n} )$$

into an explicit formula, so I can just put whatever *n* and get the *n*-th element of the sequence.

I look [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810160/convert-a-recursive-sequence-formula-to-explicit) but i can´t replicate

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The previous question you link to concerns linear recursions, while yours is quadratic.  In general, quadratic recursions can not be solved in closed form.  Of course, some quadratic recursions can be solved in closed form, in particular some, like yours, that look like [the logistic equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html).  Perhaps something on that page will help with this special case.  (though I think your case is not solvable in closed form, I might be wrong).

Comment: The cited post is about a linear recurrence relation, this is about a quadratic one. I don’t believe there is generally an explicit formula for those, even though there may be in some special cases. Are you sure such a formula exists? Alternatively, do you really need a formula? - Maybe your problem can be solved without a formula. For example, many questions about convergence, monotony, fixed points etc. can be solved without an explicit formula.

Comment: I think this is basically impossible; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map for details.

Comment: don't plug $n=1000$

Comment: You don't even give the value of $a_0$.

Comment: @Jean, presumably OP is hoping for a formula in terms of $a_0$.

Comment: $a=0$ and $a'=4/5$ are clearly fixed points of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Once $a_n$ gets large, which it will unless you start with special values that reach $0$ or $4/5$, we can ignore the $1$ to get an idea of what is happening.  Then we have $a_{n+1}=-5a_n^2$.  This would be solved by $a_n=(-5)^{n}a_0^{2^n}$ which is rapidly enormous.  It doesn't help if $|a_0| \lt 1$ unless it hits a stable point, the $1$ will take care of that.

Comment: There are other exceptional values of $a_0$, e.g., the solutions to $5x(1-x)=1$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson more exactly $5x(1-x)=x$

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  good point.  They are still discrete values, so I just left them out.

Comment: As @Jean points out, it's not just values that reach zero that are exceptional.

Comment: Are you sure, Ross, that there aren't any periodic points other than the fixed points?

Comment: No, but if the values are reals the chance of hitting one is zero.